# How to capture windows shut down/ Restart message using C++

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I want to check in  my application programmatically if user shutdown/restart/logoff the computer.
I tried to implement the below code and it giving the compilation error

```
error: invalid conversion from 'bool (*)(DWORD)' to 'BOOL (*)(DWORD)'
error: initializing argument 1 of 'BOOL SetConsoleCtrlHandler(BOOL (*)(DWORD), BOOL)'

void TestApp:: OnQuit()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, TRUE);
}

//Windows Call Back function implementation
bool WINAPI HandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
   bool ret = false;    
   if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT || dwCtrlType == CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT)
      //Graceful Quit

   return ret;
}
```

My devlopement environment is QT Creator QT SDK and C++.

Comment: A `BOOL` isn't a `bool`.

Comment: Here's the [proof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) for `BOOL` being a `typedef` of an `int`. That's why using `bool` doesn't work.

Comment: @chris, Kuba Ober -- Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, a `BOOL` is an `int`, not a `bool`.  A `bool` has nominal values of `true` and `false`, `1` and `0`.  A `BOOL` uses `FALSE == 0` and `TRUE == !FALSE`.  Mostly of no matter here since they essentially work the same way.

The `BOOL` comes from the old heritage of WinAPI when `C` didn't have a built-in `bool` type.

So, all you really need to do is change `bool` to `BOOL` in you handler:

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType)
^^^^
{
   BOOL ret = false;    
   ^^^^
   if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT || dwCtrlType == CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT)
      //Graceful Quit

   return ret;
}
```

Comment: @Wes, the code compiles fine, but never get into the method HandlerRoutine. I am wondering what wrong with the call back implementation.